# How to properly call a function from a controller and service file from test class file and display returned data in MSTest console log?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I recently facing this issue and don't how to resolve it. I'm just doing unit test with my proj but when I call a function from another service file or controller its not showing the value instead its showing this

**Result1 System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject** //conteoller result in testlog

**Controller** :

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetProjectDetails")]
public IActionResult GetProjectDetails(int ProjectID)
{
try
{
var success = teamSurveyService.GetProjectDetails(ProjectID);

```
            if (success.status == "Success")
            {
                return Ok(success);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, success);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { status = "Error", message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

**
Service :**

public dynamic GetProjectDetails(int ProjectID)
{
dynamic response = new ExpandoObject();
try
{
string connectionString = Common.Common.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings", "DefaultConnection");
List parameters = new List();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ProjectID", ProjectID));
DataTable dtProject = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spProject_GetNew", parameters.ToArray()).Tables[0];
if (dtProject.Rows.Count > 0)
{
response.status = "Success";
response.projectDetails = dtProject;
return response;
}
else
{
response.status = "Error";
response.message = "No data";
return response;
}

```
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**and the testclass file is**,

public class TestClass1
{

```
    private readonly TeamSurveyController _controller;
    private readonly ITeamSurveyService _service;
    public TestClass1()
    {
        _service = new TeamSurveyService(null);
        _controller = new TeamSurveyController(_service, null) ;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(26089)]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Test_2(int value)
    {
   
     var getProjectDetails = value;
        SuccessModel success = new SuccessModel();
        var controller =  _controller.GetProjectDetails(getProjectDetails);
        var service = _service.GetProjectDetails(getProjectDetails);
        var objectResult = controller as ObjectResult;
        var result = objectResult.Value;
        if (result.ToString() != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result1 "+ result);
            Console.WriteLine("Result1 "+ service.projectDetails);
        }
     else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result", controller);
            Console.WriteLine("result1", result);
        }

    }
```

}

If I called directly the service file its shows this in test console log

Result1 table //service result in testlog

What I want is to call the function in GetProjectDetails(ID) from controller and print the returned data in test console

I need to do unit test using mstest framework and need to call from controller file with get method